# Can Caldera forms display information for a Contact that isn't logged in?

Tags: wordpress

I think I see how to submit data to populate CiviCRM records using Caldera forms integration.  However I also need to retrieve data.  As a sample use case (over-simplified and not secure):

- Ask the visitor for an email address
- Display in the next form the first and last name in the CiviCRM Contact with that email address
- If either field is empty, display a paragraph asking that they be filled out

There's a checkbox in the Contact Processor to extract (auto populate) data for a logged in user, but that's not my situation.  If Caldera can't do this, can Webforms+Drupal?